# Не работает отображение счетчиков на кнопках соцсетей при установленном data-counter

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте!

Сгенерировал код в https://tech.yandex.ru/share/ с установленным отображением счетчиков. Но показываются только иконки. JavaScript ошибок на странице нет.

Пример - http://netall.ru/sport/interview/966930.html

С уважением, Андрианов Андрей

Comment: вижу счетчики, что не так? https://goo.gl/IIpOck

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите внимательно на документацию или на настройку подключения — счётчики поддерживают:

- Вконтакте
- Facebook
- Одноклассники
- МойМир
- Google+

при использовании остальных они не используются.

Если на странице генерации кода для подключения включить вид «счётчики», то многие скрываются, а на Вашем сайте указаны те которые на поддерживают данную возможность.

Можете например использовать 2 блока рядом.